# Python Tkinter Moving images on buttonpress

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I am trying to write a Tkinter code where it image, which looks like rain will start to move, if button called "Rain" is pressed.

I can not yet tell how the image move part works, but the problem is that when I click on the "Rain" button, it writes -> "Rain" like it should but no image appears on Canvas.

Another interesting thing is that when i take

Here is my code:

```
 root = Tk()

#Create the canvas
canvas = Canvas(width=1000, height=1000)
canvas.pack()

#This is the part that does not work
#Nothing appears when this function is called 
def Rain():
    image3 = "Drops.png"
    drops = PhotoImage(file = image3)
    drops_background = canvas1.create_image(100, 100, image=drops)
    while True:
        canvas1.move(drops_background, 10, 10)
    print("Rain")

#Adding a button and making it to use function "Rain"
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
button1 = Button(frame, text = "Rain", command = Rain, fg = "red" ).pack(side = LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Another interesting thing is that if I place this part out of the function it starts working.

```
image3 = "Drops.png"
drops = PhotoImage(file = image3)
drops_background = canvas1.create_image(100, 100, image=drops)
```

If anyone could tell me what is wrong here or at least point me in the right direction that would help me out a lot.

Comment: btw: `button1 = Button().pack()` assigns `None` to `button1` because `pack()` returns `None` - use `button1 = Button() ; button1.pack()`

Comment: Alright, thank you for that

Comment: where is `root.mainlop()` ? you have endless loop `while True` so `mainloop ()` can't do its jobs - for example it can't refresh elements like canvas.

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to add this in this code block, (that is actually not all of it so I copied the part that is not working.

Comment: you need to use `threads` to run long-running code like `while True` or use  `tk.after()` to simulate `thread`

Answer (score 2):

There is issue in `PhotoImage` (or rather in `PIL` and `Pillow` module) - `PhotoImage` must be assigned to global variable.
If `PhotoImage` is assigned to local variable then `Garbage Collector` remove it from memory.

My full working example with `after`

```
import Tkinter as tk
import random

# --- globals ---

drops_background = None
drops = None

# --- functions ---

def rain():
    global drops_background
    global drops

    filename = "Drops.png"

    drops = tk.PhotoImage(file=filename) # there is some error in PhotoImage - it have to be assigned to global variable

    drops_background = canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=drops)

    # move after 250ms
    root.after(250, move) # 250ms = 0.25s


def move():
    global drops_background

    # TODO: calculate new position
    x = random.randint(-10, 10)
    y = random.randint(-10, 10)

    # move object
    canvas.move(drops_background, x, y)

    # repeat move after 250ms
    root.after(250, move) # 250ms = 0.25s

# --- main ----

root = tk.Tk()

#Create the canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=1000, height=1000)
canvas.pack()

#This is the part that does not work
#Nothing appears when this function is called 
#Adding a button and making it to use function "Rain"
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

button1 = tk.Button(frame, text="Rain", command=rain, fg="red" )
button1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

`after` add function and time to its list and `mainloop` run function from this list after given time.

`after` expects function name without `()`